# Cell array of vectors from matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

I have a matrix of 3xN data, such as:

```
x = [1,2,3;
     4,5,6;
     7,8,9]
```

I wish to convert it into a 1xN vector of vectors with each row being a vector, such as

```
y = [[1,2,3]; 
     [4,5,6];
     [7,8,9]]
```

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Each row of a matrix ***is*** a vector. What are you attempting to do with this data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`num2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html) does just that:

```
y = num2cell(x, 2); % specify 2nd dimension
```

The result is a cell array of vectors:

```
>> x = [1,2,3; 4,5,6; 7,8,9];
>> y = num2cell(x, 2)
y =
  3×1 cell array
    {1×3 double}
    {1×3 double}
    {1×3 double}
>> celldisp(y)
y{1} =
     1     2     3
y{2} =
     4     5     6
y{3} =
     7     8     9
```

Comment: Ah, thanks, much appreciated! how would you go about merging it by the columns instead of row-wise, by the way? Simply by not mentioning the 2nd dimension, or `y = num2cell(x, 1);`?

Comment: @Terrornado You use `y = num2cell(x, 1)` for that. With `y = num2cell(x)` you would get a 2D cell array with each number in a cell

Answer (score 1):

The elements of a vector or matrix are by definition scalars, a vector of vectors is not possible in matlab. You could instead use a cell array of vectors  `{[1,2,3];[4,5,6];[7,8,9]}`

Comment: ah yeah, looking for a cell array of vectors, sorry for the misunderstanding!

Answer (score 1):

In MATLAB, matrices (or numeric vectors as they are the same type) can only have scalar elements, as in your `x` example.

To achieve your `y`, you have to use a cell array, which could be created using `arrayfun`:

```
>> y = arrayfun( @(ii) x(ii,:), 1:size(x,1), 'uni', 0 );
y = 
   {[1 2 3], [4 5 6], [7 8 9]};
```

You now need to index using curly braces like `y{1}` for `[1 2 3]`. Note that you now can't take advantage of the vectorisation which the original matrix could have offered for any mathematical operations later in your code.